# Firebase isEmailVerified is not working kotlin android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I have an issue with .isEmailVerified. I would like my activity to check if a user has verified the account. Unfortunately, when calling this function I get an error "Expecting member declaration." I am still a beginner.

Part of my code:

```kotlin
class EmailVerificationActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var auth : FirebaseAuth

    private fun ifVerified(currentUser: FirebaseUser?) {
        val user = auth.currentUser

            if (user!!.isEmailVerified) {
                startActivity(Intent(this, PersonalInformationActivity::class.java))
            }
    }

    ifVerified()
```

Comment: Isn't `.isEmailVerified` a function that needs to be called? `.isEmailVerified()`. I don't know the Kotlin API, but this would be my first guess.

Comment: It also doesn't work

Comment: Do you have any other idea?

Comment: At which line of code are you getting the error?  Please respond with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I had to do was just to reload the user.

```kotlin
    private fun ifVerified() {
        val user = auth.currentUser
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.reload()?.addOnSuccessListener {
                void ->
            var user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
            if (user?.isEmailVerified == true) {
                startActivity(Intent(this, PersonalInformationActivity::class.java))

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private fun ifVerified(currentUser: FirebaseUser?) {
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()    //<- initialize your FirebaseAuth object first

    val user = auth.currentUser

    if (user!!.isEmailVerified) {
        startActivity(Intent(this, PersonalInformationActivity::class.java))

        finish()    //<- why need this?
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I implement it inside override fun onCreate?